# Null pointer exception in spark for boolean and nested beans

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to build a spark dataset for a bean class, which has a field which itself is a bean and a boolean field, however I get a null pointer exception while doing so. If I use a double instead of a boolean for the second field, the null pointer exception is gone.

Below is the cope snippet:

```
SparkSession  spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").getOrCreate();
Encoder<cR> cREncoder = Encoders.bean(cR.class);

cR cR1 = new cR (4.5, new c("abc"));
cR cR2 = new  cR(5.5, new c("xyz"));
List<cR > listcR = Arrays.asList (cR1,cR2);

Dataset<cR > cRData= spark.createDataset(listcR,cREncoder);
System.out.println ("Duration in Main " + cR1.getDuration());
System.out.println ("Duration in Main " + cR2.getDuration());
cRData.printSchema();
cRData.show();

public class cR implements java.io.Serializable {
    public double duration;
//    public Boolean version;
    public c _c;

    public cR (double v, c cu) {
      this.duration = v;
      this._c = cu;
//      this.version = ver;
        System.out.println("Duration : " + this.duration);
    }

// getter setter methods for data member
}

public class c implements java.io.Serializable {
    public String id;

    public c (String s) {
      id= s;
    }

//getter and setters

}
```

Comment: Boolean is an object whereas double is a primitive.

Comment: Still even if its an object, why is it not working?

Comment: Can you be more specific about where the NullPointerException is occurring?  It's hard to tell from your commented out code what the original problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks an existing Spark issue been existing for long. The workaround is to replace all Boolean to boolean in your bean class.